# How does Spark SQL decide the number of partitions it will use when loading data from a Hive table?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

This question is same as [Number of partitions of a spark dataframe created by reading the data from Hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886868/number-of-partitions-of-a-spark-dataframe-created-by-reading-the-data-from-hive)

But I think  that question did not get a correct answer. Note that the question is asking how many partitions will be created when the dataframe is created as a result of executing a sql query against a HIVE table using [SparkSession.sql](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#sql(java.lang.String)) method.

IIUC, the question above is distinct from asking how many partitions will be created when the dataframe is created as a result of executing some code like `spark.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")` which loads the data directly from the filesystem - which could be HDFS. I think the answer to this latter question is given by [spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html)

> spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes 134217728 (128 MB)  The maximum
>   number of bytes to pack into a single partition when reading files.

Experimentally, I have tried creating a dataframe from a HIVE table and the # of partitions I get is not explained by `total data in hive table / spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`

Also adding to the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886868/number-of-partitions-of-a-spark-dataframe-created-by-reading-the-data-from-hive), it would be good to know how can the number of partitions be controlled i.e., when one wants to force spark to use a different number than it would by default.

References:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The default number of partitions when reading data from Hive will be governed by the HDFS blockSize. The number of partitions can be increased by setting [mapreduce.job.maps](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) to appropriate value, and can be decreased by setting [mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) to appropriate value

Spark SQL creates an instance of [HadoopRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.html) when loading data from a hive table.

> An RDD that provides core functionality for reading data stored in
>   Hadoop (e.g., files in HDFS, sources in HBase, or S3), using the older
>   MapReduce API (org.apache.hadoop.mapred).

[image]

HadoopRDD in turn splits input files according to the `computeSplitSize` method defined in [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.11/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html) (the new API) and [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html#line.381) (the old API).

New API:

```
protected long computeSplitSize(long blockSize, long minSize,
                                  long maxSize) {
    return Math.max(minSize, Math.min(maxSize, blockSize));
  }
```

Old API:

```
protected long computeSplitSize(long goalSize, long minSize,
                                       long blockSize) {
    return Math.max(minSize, Math.min(goalSize, blockSize));
  }
```

computeSplitSize splits files according to the HDFS blockSize but if the blockSize is less than `minSize` or greater than `maxSize` then it is clamped to those extremes. The HDFS blockSize can be obtained from

```
hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.blocksize
```

According to Hadoop the definitive guide Table 8.5, the `minSize` is obtained from `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` and the `maxSize` is obtained from `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`.

[image]

However, the book also mentions regarding `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` that:

> This property is not present
>   in the old MapReduce API (with the exception of
>   CombineFileInputFormat). Instead, it is calculated indirectly as the
>   size of the total input for the job, divided by the guide number of
>   map tasks specified by mapreduce.job.maps (or the setNumMapTasks()
>   method on JobConf).

[this](http://www.bigsynapse.com/spark-input-output) post also calculates the maxSize using the total input size divided by the number of map tasks.

Comment: what I dont understand is, using Parquet to get a particular column (SELECT id FROM parquet), Spark will create 1 task per 1 HDFS block whereas the data could be in a single block?

Comment: Is the answer still valid with new releases?