# what's the number of partitions when spark sql read a hive table?

Tags: apache-spark

After reading up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061443/how-does-spark-sql-decide-the-number-of-partitions-it-will-use-when-loading-data) , i know the number of partitions when reading data from Hive will be decided by the HDFS blockSize.

But i meet a problem: i use spark sql to read a hive table, and save the data to an new hive table, but the two hive tables have different partition numbers when loaded by spark sql.

```
  val data = spark.sql("select * from src_table")
  val partitionsNum = data.rdd.getNumPartitions
  println(partitionsNum)
  val newData = data
newData.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").saveAsTable("new_table")
```

I don't understand the same data, why different partition numbers.

Comment: Spark SQL doesn't depend on Hadoop configuration anymore: [How to change partition size in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38249624/9613318). And there is not enough detail here. What is format of the input? How has it been stored?